# What's wrong with my realloc doing on 2d-array

Tags: c, malloc, global-variables, 2d, realloc

I am solving [binary tree paths](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-paths/) leet code programming question 257. I am having issue for one of the larger input where my code is getting segmentation fault. I suspect that there is an problem with my realloc but I am not able to figure it out.

Below is my approach:

Initially I started by dynamically allocating 80 bytes of memory of type char `(80/8 = 10 rows)`and storing the returned address to `char **res` variable.

`char ** res = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * sum);`

I am calling `findpath` function recursively to find all the binary tree paths. Whenever one path is found , I dynamic allocate 100 bytes for each row index.

`res[resIdx] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);`

I have one global variable `resIdx` which points to the current row index where I copy the found binary tree path and increment the global variable `resIdx`.

if the `resIdx` becomes greater then total number of rows which was previously allocated then I do realloc of the memory but it looks like realloc is getting failed.

```
    if (resIdx >= sum)
    {
       sum = sum + 10;
       res = (char **)realloc(res,sizeof(char *) * sum);  //Any issue here?
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out what's wrong I am doing in my code. Below is my full code

```
/**
* Definition for a binary tree node.
* struct TreeNode {
*     int val;
*     struct TreeNode *left;
*     struct TreeNode *right;
* };
*/


/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */

int sum;
int resIdx;
void findpath (struct TreeNode* root, int *ls,int ls_idx,char **res);
char ** binaryTreePaths(struct TreeNode* root, int* returnSize){

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        *returnSize = 0;
        return NULL;
    }
    resIdx = 0;
    sum = 10;
    char ** res = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * sum);
    int ls[100];
    findpath(root,&ls[0],0,res);
    *returnSize = resIdx;
    return &res[0];

}


void findpath (struct TreeNode* root, int *ls,int ls_idx,char **res)
{
    char temp[100];
    int l=0,i=0;
    if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    {
        ls[ls_idx] = root->val;
        ls_idx+=1;
        if (resIdx >= sum)
        {
           sum = sum + 10;
           res = (char **)realloc(res,sizeof(char *) * sum);
        }
  
        res[resIdx] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        while (i < ls_idx)
        {
            if (i==0)
            {
                l = l + sprintf(&temp[l], "%d", ls[i]);

            }
            else
            {
                l = l + sprintf(&temp[l], "->%d", ls[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
        strcpy(res[resIdx],temp);
        resIdx++;
        return; 
    }  
    ls[ls_idx] = root->val;
    if (root->left != NULL)
    {
        findpath(root->left,ls,ls_idx+1,res);   
    }

    if (root->right != NULL)
    {
        findpath(root->right,ls,ls_idx+1,res); 
    }
    return;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last argument to your `findPath` function is declared as a `char**` type; thus, when you make the call `findpath(root,&ls[0],0,res);` in `binaryTreePaths`, where the `res` variable is a `char**` type, a ***copy*** of that pointer is passed to the `findPath` function (most likely, but not *necessarily*, by placing that copy on the stack).

Then, if reallocation is required, the `res = (char **)realloc(res,sizeof(char *) * sum);` line in that function overwrites the value ***in the passed copy*** and, at the same time (if the call is successful – *vide infra*), will (probably) invalidate (i.e. free) the memory referenced by the previous address in that `res` copy. Thus, when control returns to the calling `binaryTreePaths` function, its *own* version of `res` will *not* have been modified and will remain pointing to that (now invalid) memory.

So, in order for your `findPath` function to be able to modify the given `res` argument, that must be passed as a pointer – in this case, a pointer to a `char**`, which will be of type `char***`; then, when called, you will need to pass the *address* of the `res` variable in `binaryTreePaths`.

Note also that directly overwriting a pointer in a call to `realloc`, as you have done in the line of code quoted above is dangerous. This is because, should that call fail, then you have lost the original data pointer (it will have been overwritten with `NULL`) and error recovery will be very difficult. You should save the return value in a temporary variable and only replace your original if the call succeeds.

With the code you have provided, I cannot properly test for any other errors but, taking the points above in hand, the below is a possible fix. See also: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073)

```c
int sum;
int resIdx;
void findpath(struct TreeNode* root, int* ls, int ls_idx, char*** res); // Note last argument type!

char** binaryTreePaths(struct TreeNode* root, int* returnSize)
{
    if (root == NULL) {
        *returnSize = 0;
        return NULL;
    }
    resIdx = 0;
    sum = 10;
    char** res = malloc(sizeof(char*) * sum);
    int ls[100];
    findpath(root, &ls[0], 0, &res); // Pass ADDRESS of res
    *returnSize = resIdx;
    return &res[0];
}

void findpath(struct TreeNode* root, int* ls, int ls_idx, char*** res)
{
    char temp[100];
    int l = 0, i = 0;
    if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
        ls[ls_idx] = root->val;
        ls_idx += 1;
        if (resIdx >= sum) {
            sum = sum + 10;
            char** test = realloc(*res, sizeof(char*) * sum);
            if (test == NULL) {
                // Handle/signal error
                return;
            }
            *res = test; // Only replace original if realloc succeeded!
        }
        (*res)[resIdx] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        while (i < ls_idx) {
            if (i == 0) {
                l = l + sprintf(&temp[l], "%d", ls[i]);
            }
            else {
                l = l + sprintf(&temp[l], "->%d", ls[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
        strcpy((*res)[resIdx], temp);
        resIdx++;
        return;
    }
    ls[ls_idx] = root->val;
    if (root->left != NULL) {
        findpath(root->left, ls, ls_idx + 1, res);
    }
    if (root->right != NULL) {
        findpath(root->right, ls, ls_idx + 1, res);
    }
    return;
}
```